# 1and1 htaccess file not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've created a website on my localhost and having uploaded it to my 1and1.co.uk account, I'm getting a 500 internal server error.

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is the contents of the htaccess file on localhost and it's causing a 500 internal server error now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace those lines:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999
```

Setting php_flag and php_value is regulary forbidden in shared hosting environment. Add the following lines to the begin of your index.php instead:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Btw, I see that you are using an `error_reporting` level of `9999`. This looks weired to me. Note that `error_reporting` isn't an integer value that can be incremented to output more errors, it is a bitfield instead. Refer to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Comment: I'm so grateful for that, it's sorted it immediately. I don't have a great knowledge of htaccess files, hosts etc so I wouldn't have known that in another year of trying! Thanks bud.

Comment: @Luke You are welcome. Note that it is not a syntax error. It's just forbidden by the admin. You configure which values can be set in .htaccess using the apache.conf

Comment: It's an area I definitely need to look into more. The error reporting 9999 came from somewhere else as I didn't understand the htaccess file enough. I'll do some research with apache server settings etc and learn more!