# why php controller not loading error file

Tags: php, model-view-controller

i am bilding a mvc app in php

the app can't load error controller

when i try to check if there is an error

it stop and give me blank page

i have this files below

this is the  .htaccess file :

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /aiosx/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

i have this main app file

```
private $_url = null;
private $_controller = null;
private $_controllerPath = 'controllers/'; // Always include trailing slash
private $_modelPath = 'models/'; // Always include trailing slash
private $_errorFile = 'error.php';
private $_defaultFile = 'dashboard.php';

public function init(){-
    $this->_getUrl();-
    if (empty($this->_url[0])) {
        $this->_loadDefaultController();
        return false;
    }
    $this->_loadExistingController();
    $this->_callControllerMethod();
}
public function setControllerPath($path) {
    $this->_controllerPath = trim($path, '/') . '/';
}    
public function setModelPath($path) {
    $this->_modelPath = trim($path, '/') . '/';
}
public function setErrorFile($path) {
    $this->_errorFile = trim($path, '/');
}
public function setDefaultFile($path) {
    $this->_defaultFile = trim($path, '/');
}
private function _getUrl() {
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $this->_url = explode('/', $url);
}
private function _loadDefaultController() {
    require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;
    $this->_controller = new Dashboard();
    $this->_controller->index();
}
private function _loadExistingController() {
    $file = $this->_controllerPath . $this->_url[0] . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        $this->_controller = new $this->_url[0];
        $this->_controller->loadModel($this->_url[0], $this->_modelPath);
    } else {
        $this->_error();
        return false;
    }
}
private function _callControllerMethod() {
    $length = count($this->_url);       
    if ($length > 1) {
        if (!method_exists($this->_controller, $this->_url[1])) {
            $this->_error();
        }
    }
    switch ($length) {
        case 5:
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2], $this->_url[3], $this->_url[4]);
            break;            
        case 4:
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2], $this->_url[3]);
            break;            
        case 3:
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2]);
            break;            
        case 2:
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}();
            break;            
        default:
            $this->_controller->index();
            break;
    }
}    
private function _error() {
    require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_errorFile;
    $this->_controller = new Error();
    $this->_controller->index();
    exit;
}
```

why this app is not loading the erorr controller
i have been check every thing please help me

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC. What you seem to be having problem with is "url routing", "class autoloading" and "dispatching".

Comment: "it stop and give me blank page"  Have you checked your error logs to see _why_?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429977/1and1-htaccess-file-not-working.
Also, have you checked the error logs when you get the blank page. Usually it means there is a server error that is not being displayed and logged instead

Comment: I highly doubt that 9999 is the error reporting level you intended. This represents `E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_USER_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED`. See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php.